# Subquery returns more than one row? Can't write in database

Tags: subquery

I have a problem with my PHP-Script. I want to insert data into my database but the only thing it returns is an Error.

**Code:**

```
<?php
require_once('ConnectionHandler.php');

Class CreateTask
{

    public function createNewTask($description, $subject, $type, $enddate, $priority)
    {

        $query = 'INSERT INTO task (description, subject_id, task_type_id, enddate, priority) VALUES (?, (SELECT id_subject FROM subject WHERE name = ?), (SELECT id_task_type FROM task_type WHERE type = ?), ?, ?)';

        $statement = ConnectionHandler::getConnection()->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('siisi', $description, $subject, $type, $enddate, $priority);

        if (!$statement->execute()) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

In the ConnectionHandler it set up the Connection to the database.

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' in E:\xampp\htdocs\lib\CreateTask.php:16 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\homelogedin.php(21): CreateTask->createNewTask('fgdgdsg', 'Mathematics', 'Exam', '2015-05-31', '3') #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\pages\index.php(4): require_once('E:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\lib\CentralDesign.php(35): require_once('E:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(9): CentralDesign->loadPage() #4 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\lib\CreateTask.php on line 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't use `INSERT INTO` that way. Subquerys are not allowed in this context. But scalar expressions will to the trick:

```
INSERT INTO task (description, subject_id, task_type_id, enddate, priority)
SELECT 'desc', A.id_subject, B.id_task_type, '2015-05-05', 2
FROM 
  (SELECT id_subject FROM subject WHERE name = 'Blau') A,
  (SELECT id_task_type FROM task_type WHERE type = 'typ1') B
```

Best regards, binzram

PS:
Next time take the lil journey to my desk.